# why the duplicated cases are counted twice in probability?

Tags: probability

Question : What is the probability of getting a sum 9 from two throws of a dice?

assumption : throwing a dice twice is same as throwing two dice once.

please let me know this assumption is correct or not.

my solution is :

total cases = 36

favourable cases : (3,6)(4,5)(5,4)(6,3)

but (3,6)==(6,3)
and (4,5)==(5,4)

so answer should be 2/32.

but the given answer is 4/32.

please tell me where I am lacking.

Comment: If you consider (3, 6) and (6, 3) to be the same case, then how did you get a total of 36 cases?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė if I don not cont 36 , then my favourable cases will be 21(1+2+3+4+5+6). which gives 2/21 answer

Comment: I wasn't implying that the answers would match. Only that you got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider $(6, 3)$ and $(3, 6)$ to be the same case. An experiment would reveal to you, however, that this case is twice as likely, compared to $(1, 1)$. The formula $P = \frac {\text{favorable cases}} {\text{total cases}}$ only works with all cases equally likely, so you end up with the wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing a die twice is indeed the same as throwing two dice once.

The problem is when you say $(3,6)=(6,3)$. This is not true, and these are two different ways to roll a $9$. You can see this by coloring one of the dice blue, the other red; then, the 4 ways to roll a nine are
$$
\color{blue}{3},\color{red}{6} \quad \color{blue}{4},\color{red}{5} \quad \color{blue}{5},\color{red}{4} \quad \color{blue}{6},\color{red}{3}
$$

Comment: both the dice are same !!!
so why I can not consider (3,6)=(6,3).because when I consider both dice are same , 3 on any die and 6 on any die is same as 6 on any die and 3 on any die

Comment: Let's say you flip two identical coins: what is the probability of exactly one head? By your logic, the coins are the same, so there are 3 equally likely events (0 heads, 1 head, 2heads), meaning $P($ one head $)=1/3$. But clearly we have $P(HH)=1/4$ (each coin is independent, with $P(H)=1/2$), and $P(TT)=1/4$, so we must have $P($ one head $)=1-\frac14-\frac14=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying there are 36 cases then it can't be the case that $(3,6)=(6,3)$, since you must have counted these as different when finding the number 36.

Comment: if I don not cont 36 , then my favourable cases will be 21(1+2+3+4+5+6). which gives 2/21 answer ,